# Render download link sanity.io result in a blank page

Tags: reactjs, sanity, headless-cms

I'm new diving into sanity.io and I'm trying to figure out why is displaying a blank page.
N.B. If I comment out the  the JSON.stringify display everything correct, including the cvURL link.

This is the code

```
export default {
      name: 'curriculum',
      title: 'Curriculum',
      type: 'document',
      fields: [
            {
                  name: 'title',
                  type: 'string',
                  title: 'Title'
            },
            {
                  title: 'Cv',
                  name: 'cv',
                  type: 'file',


            },

            {
                  name: 'description',
                  type: 'string',
                  title: 'Description'
            },


      ]
}
```

and this is the component:

```
 const [cv, setCv] = useState(null);
      useEffect(() => {
            sanityClient
                  .fetch(

                        `*[_type == 'curriculum'] {
  title,
  description,
  curriculum,
  cv,
  "cvURL": cv.asset->url
}`)
                  .then((data) => setCv(data))
                  .catch(console.error);
      }, []);

      return (
            <div>
                  <a href={`${cv.cvURL}`}>This is my CV</a>
                  <pre>{JSON.stringify(cv)}</pre>
            </div>

      )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry, if I comment out the (a href )....

Answer (score 1):

cv is an Array. so, Either use map() function or use cv[0] because it's only one array Element.
Here is your answer Change Your anchor Tag.

```js
<a href={`${cv[0].cvURL}?dl=<filename-of-your-choice.pdf>`} >This is my CV</a>
```

If it does not work then store cv as an Array like this

```js
const [cv, setCv] = useState([]);
```